# How to set a default context for subwidget via binding from main widget in AggreGate?

Tags: iot

I want to change the Default Context property for subwidget by binding in the main widget via the Node Selection event in the System Tree component.
I added a binding to the main widget. Expression with string context path is evaluated on Node Selected event. The result of the expression is written to the Default Context property of subwidget via  binding target.
[image]

In the widget Event Log show binding start, why default context in subwidget is always "empty string"?
[image]

What am I doing wrong and where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The Default Context property of the Subwidget component must contain Expression! Wrap string context path in escaped quotes, or write string path as a reference with "{}" characters. See screenshots.
[image]

[image]
[image]